# Unpermitted parameter: format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parameters

I don't understand why I'm geting these `Unpermitted parameter: format` messages, I'm doing a JSON request: `POST "/questions/add_options.json"` with these parameters `Parameters: {"id_question"=>551, "options"=>[{"position"=>10, "label"=>"opc 10", "value"=>"opc 10", "go_page"=>nil}], "question"=>{}}` and this is what I get in the terminal...

```
Started POST "/questions/add_options.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-16 23:12:27 -0300
Processing by QuestionsController#add_options as JSON
  Parameters: {"id_question"=>551, "options"=>[{"position"=>10, "label"=>"opc 10", "value"=>"opc 10", "go_page"=>nil}], "question"=>{}}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "login_aexa".* FROM "login_aexa" WHERE "login_aexa"."usuaex_id" = $1  ORDER BY "login_aexa"."usuaex_id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["usuaex_id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: format
  Question Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 551]]
Unpermitted parameter: format
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "options" WHERE "options"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 551]]
```

In the Rails controller I use params permit to reject parameters that are not allowed, like this:

```
def question_add_options_params
  params.permit(:id_question, options: [:position, :label, :value, :go_page], question: {})
end
```

In my opinion the format should be fine, anyone know why I'm getting those `Unpermitted parameter: format` messages?

**EDIT**:

Here's the code of the controller

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /questions
  # GET /questions.json
  def index
    @questions = Question.all
  end

  # GET /questions/1
  # GET /questions/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /questions/new
  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end

  # GET /questions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /questions
  # POST /questions.json
  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.save
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /questions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /questions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.update(question_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def add_options
    @question = Question.find(question_add_options_params[:id_question])

    question_add_options_params[:options].each do|q_aop|
      @question.options.create(q_aop)
    end

    @options = @question.options
  end

  # DELETE /questions/1
  # DELETE /questions/1.json
  def destroy
    @question.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to questions_url, notice: 'Question was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def question_params
      params[:question]
    end

    def question_add_options_params
      params.permit(:id_question, options: [:position, :label, :value, :go_page])
    end
end
```

Comment: what does your controller action look like? do you have a format block?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: @MarsAtomic It's rails 4.2.5

Comment: @Doon I have a `respond_to do |format|`, but it's not in the `add_options` action, in any case I'ill edit the post to add the code of the controller

Answer (score 9):

```
params.permit(:id_question, options: [:position, :label, :value, :go_page], question: {})
```

This line is telling Rails that the *only* params that are permitted are in the list above.
If you actually look at a real params-hash, it doesn't just contain the params passed in by the form, it also contains things like: `:controller => :questions, :action => :create, :format => :json` etc... which Rails always inserts based on the URL

Normally we namespace the form by using eg `form_for @question` which means the params come in like this:

```
{:controller => :questions, :action => :create,
 :format => :json,
 :question => {"id_question"=>551, "options"=>[{"position"=>10, "label"=>"opc 10", "value"=>"opc 10", "go_page"=>nil}]}
}
```

then you can do this in your controller:

```
params.require(:question).permit(:id_question, options: [:position, :label, :value, :go_page])
```

which doesn't literally tell rails that you aren't allowed to have the controller/action/format params that are *always* passed in by rails...

Obviously you'll need to modify the names of these to suit your needs, but this is what you need to do to stop the error.

Comment: Ok... but I didn't use a form from Rails, I'm sending those JSON params from an AngularJS application using Restangular... so I'm sending those params with javascript code.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you're sending them to Rails Rails pulls those other fields out of the URL you use... and once your Rails app receives them... you need to tell Rails that they are acceptable fields.

Comment: Requests include extra params ("format", "controller", and "action"). Rails will complain about this if you don't "require" a field. To hide that warning, you can exclude "format" from your parameters: params.except(:format).permit(:id_question, options: [:position, :label, :value, :go_page])

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with my JSON and thought this question could use a few more examples.

#### TL;DR

To avoid the `Unpermitted parameter: format` with JSON requests be sure to nest your request object for POST and PATCH requests (ex. `{ question: {name: '', prompt: ''} }` and access with `params.require(:question).permit(:name, :prompt, ..)` in the controller. For GET and DELETE requests, use only `params.require(:id)` in the controller.

To build on [Taryn's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38988129/1038034) above, I needed to create a nested object in my front end for POST requests, and fix how I was using `require` and `permit` on the back end. Here are examples:

#### Example: `POST /questions`

Rails expects a post request to be of the form, `{ question: { name: '', prompt: '', ..} }`. In the front end:

```
// bad
$http.post('/questions.json', { name: 'Question 1', prompt: 'Bears eat beets?' })

// good
$http.post('/questions.json', { question: { name: 'Question 1', prompt: '...' } })
```

Backend:

```
# app/controllers/questions_controller.rb
def question_params
  # bad - logs 'Unpermitted parameter: format'
  params.permit(:name, :prompt)

  # good
  params.require(:question).permit(:name, :prompt)
end
```

#### Example: `GET /questions/:id`

My mistake was in the backend again. For example:

```
# app/controllers/questions_controller.rb
def show
  # bad - logs 'Unpermitted parameter: format'
  question = Question.where(params.permit(:id)).first
  
  # good
  question = Question.find(params.require(:id))
  render json: question
end
```

Answer (score -7):

```
<%= link_to "Questinons", questions_path(format: "json") %>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this code will solve the OP's problem?