# Unpermitted parameter: :format when saving image with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage, carrierwave, fog

I am trying to save my image files with carrierwave, fog, and google cloud storage.

So when I submit the data and the image field

> ```
> <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile>
> ```
>
> but getting error "Unpermitted parameter: :format".

This worked well with Amazon S3, but I already payed for the gcp, so I want to save images here.

Give me some tips please. Thank you

image_uploader.rb

```rb
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

fog.rb

```rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_provider = 'fog/google'
    config.fog_credentials = {
        provider:              'Goggle',
        aws_access_key_id:     ENV['GOOGLE_ACCESS_KEY'],
        aws_secret_access_key: ENV['GOOGLE_SEC_KEY'],
        #region:                'ap-northeast-1',
        #endpoint:              'https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'
        endpoint:              'https://storage.googleapis.com'
    }
    config.fog_directory  = 'fullout-linemanager-storage'
    config.fog_public     = true
    config.fog_attributes = { }

    config.remove_previously_stored_files_after_update = true
end
```

reaction.rb(Model)

```rb
class Reaction < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :file, ImageUploader
end
```

reactions_controller.rb

```rb
(...)
def reaction_params
    if params[:reaction].present?
      params[:reaction][:channel_id] = current_user.target_channel
      params[:reaction][:target_number] = 0
      params.require(:reaction).permit(
        :id, :name, :contents, :reaction_type ,:channel_id, :tag, :target_number,
        :image, :created_at, :updated_at, :match_option
        )
    else
      params[:channel_id] = current_user.target_channel
      params[:target_number] = 0
      params.permit(
        :id, :name, :contents, :reaction_type ,:channel_id, :tag, :target_number, :created_at, :updated_at, :match_option, :image
        )
    end
  end
```

log

```
Parameters: {"name"=>"text_welcome_message", "reaction_type"=>"image", "contents"=>"[ NO TEXT ]", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f91f79a9968 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/jb/qnz4lt193kz7wzj06xrp9q5w0000gn/T/RackMultipart20200204-6757-1h92oyl.png>, @original_filename="Ad-2.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"Ad-2.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "tag"=>"ALL", "match_option"=>"1"}
12:09:10 web.1       |   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
12:09:10 web.1       |   ↳ app/controllers/api/reactions_controller.rb:188
12:09:10 web.1       | Unpermitted parameter: :format
12:09:10 web.1       |   Option Load (7.7ms)  SELECT  `options`.* FROM `options` WHERE `options`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
12:09:10 web.1       |   ↳ app/controllers/api/reactions_controller.rb:63
12:09:10 web.1       |    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
12:09:10 web.1       |   ↳ app/controllers/api/reactions_controller.rb:64
12:09:10 web.1       |    (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
12:09:10 web.1       |   ↳ app/controllers/api/reactions_controller.rb:64
12:09:10 web.1       | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 8.8ms)
```

Comment: What's in line 64 of `reactions_controller.rb`?

Comment: it is a controller for my model "Reaction"

Comment: The possible solution you can find in this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/a/38988129/11293192

Answer (score 0):

Whatever request client you're using in the front application is sending the `format` parameter which is clearly not permitted in your controller. It might just be a harmless `format: 'json'`. If that's the case, you can just filter this parameter using the `except` method in your action and the problem might be solved:

```
params.except(:format).require(:reaction).permit(:id, :name, :contents, :reaction_type ,:channel_id, :tag, :target_number, :image, :created_at, :updated_at, :match_option)
```

and

```
params.except(:format).permit(:id, :name, :contents, :reaction_type ,:channel_id, :tag, :target_number, :created_at, :updated_at, :match_option, :image)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to make a few more changes to the supplied fog configuration. First, I think for provider you'll want `Google` instead of `Goggle`. Next, you'll want to change from the current usage of aws related credential keys to the google specific ones (I suspect this is the cause of your actual error, fwiw). So instead of `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` you will want `google_storage_access_key` and `google_storage_secret_access_key`). You can see a bit more about this in the carrierwave readme here: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-google-storage-for-developers

Altogether, the resulting fog.rb would look something like this:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_provider = 'fog/google'
    config.fog_credentials = {
        provider:                         'Google',
        google_storage_access_key:        ENV['GOOGLE_ACCESS_KEY'],
        google_storage_secret_access_key: ENV['GOOGLE_SEC_KEY'],
    }
    config.fog_directory  = 'fullout-linemanager-storage'
    config.fog_public     = true
    config.fog_attributes = { }

    config.remove_previously_stored_files_after_update = true
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried this way but there was another problem. The image file cannot be saved. I checked the log file, and the data did "rollback" right after "insert".

Comment: Hmm. That sounds more like a local and/or database concern, rather than something in fog (which would handle things over the wire). It's hard to know the particular problem without further details though.

Comment: I did the same with fog-aws, and it worked. So I think there might be something wrong in fog-google. Thank you for your support!